# Load tables into SQL Server from SparklyR

Tags: sql-server, r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

As of October 2017, is it possible to write Sparklyr Spark Data Frames into SQL Server?

I got this error:

```
> DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "DZ_test", for_test)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature 
‘"Microsoft SQL Server", "character", "tbl_spark"’
```

I'm currently running:

- dplyr 0.7.4
- sparklyr 0.6.3
- Spark 2.0.1 built for Hadoop 2.7.3

There is something similar for Cassandra in the wonderful `crassy` package, but not sure if there is a connector or method for SQL Server. Thanks!

SOLVED!!!

I used the jdbc driver for SQL server. I had jdk 1.8, so that meant I used the driver for Java 8 on all nodes:

```
spark.jars.packages com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.2.2.jre8
```

I put this in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

I typically log into the SQL server using kerberos authentication, but since that was not set up on all nodes of my test cluster I made a SQL login for the database of interest (required an administrator) and connected via that username/pass.

```
spark_write_jdbc(my_sdf, "my_sdf", 
                 options = list(
                   url=paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://cwjensql10.cwjwin.local;",
                              "databaseName=HER_NILM;",
                              "user=HER;",
                              "password=Test1;"),
                   driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
)
```

If you want to use Kerberos authentication (and are running on linux) it would look as such:

```
spark_write_jdbc(my_sdf, "my_sdf", 
                 options = list(
                   url=paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://cwjensql10.cwjwin.local;",
                              "databaseName=HER_NILM;",
                              "integratedSecurity=true;",
                              "authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;"),
                   driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
)
```

For Windows, just don't include the `authenticationScheme` option.

Big thanks to @user6910411!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sparklyr::spark_write_jdbc`](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/spark_write_jdbc.html) function to write data directly from Spark without collecting data in R. To make it work, you'll need [an appropriate JDBC driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) available on the driver and worker nodes.

Assuming driver is already included using `spark.jars.packages`, you'll need something similar to:

```
spark_write_jdbc(
  df, "some_name", 
  options=list(
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://...",
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"))
```